# Google Forms to spreadsheet edit responses and new responses on the top

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I've created a Google form and I want to be able to drag the rows into categories below it, but I want the new responses to always show up at the top. Instead, it follows the previous row.

For example:

[image]

So the responses come in under the yellow. As I work through the client, they will get moved to another section that I've created — the blue headings that are not part of the form, just the spreadsheet.

So the last response entered is #8, if I drag #8 into the Paid section, when response number 9 is entered into the form, it will automatically create a new line below #8 also in the paid section. Basically, I want any new response to always create a new row #2. That way it always stays at the top until I move it.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is very possible, there are a couple ways to do this.

1. You could index everything with unique numbers and use filters to help you.  May get complicated and messy.
2. You could use a view with another sheet to give you the Master view and then you can use your worksheet as the working copy.  Think of a dashboard of sorts, granted i need to understand a little more of what your are trying to do but its possible.
3. Finally, there is actually using code to do this.  Google Appscripts are very powerful and you could do anything with the Javascript behind Google.

Obviously, you wanted an answer that could show you how to do it, if you share a view only public version with a sample data I could see what I could do or one of our community members could also take a look.

Part of this will depend on your comfort level.  If you don't know scripting we can certainly show you a couple native functions that could get you down the right path.

Comment: Here is the link to a spreadsheet.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XnXCPnFNmMO6Kc_1HDCV3_ahwiRr3J33_MqR1jpaqnc/edit?usp=sharing

I want the new responses to always show up in the top under the yellow section.  Then I want the ability to drag them down the appropriate section below without the subsequent response filling in directly below it.